# Replace GET method in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite the URL by accessing the directory and not actually referencing index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\ .php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+) /?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Basically, I am trying to:

```
    Change:
localhost/?page=Main

    To:
localhost/Main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/*([a-zA-Z]+) index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteRule ^/?page=(.*)$ /$1
```

should work you need the rewrite module enabled though

Comment: This causes a 500 error for any page I access. The rewrite module is enabled.

Comment: Remove the `=` sign from the RewriteCond: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET`